# Mapped Type For Optional Arguments

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

```
interface Foo{
  one: string;
  two?: number;
  someFunc: (args: string|number) => string
}
```

So, what i am looking for is a way to declare the type for 'args';

I was wondering if there was a way to specify the type for args.The paramater 'two' is optional. In case the user specifies the parameter 'two', i want someFunc to have args as number and string other wise, is there a way of doing this except using union type.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a union instead of the interface. One union member will have `two` required an if type number, and have the appropriate type for `args`, the other member of the union will have `two`optional and of type `never` to ensure its not compatible with the other union member. You will loose inference for the argument type, but the compiler will validate that the function does have the appropriate parameter type.

```
type Foo = {
    one: string;
    two?: never;
    someFunc: (args: number) => string
} | {
    one: string;
    two: number;
    someFunc: (args: string) => string
}

let foo: Foo = {
    one: '',
    someFunc : (a: string) => a
} // err

let foo2: Foo = {
    one: '',
    someFunc : (a: number) => a.toString()
} // ok

let foo3: Foo = {
    one: '',
    two:2,
    someFunc : (a: string) => a
} // ok

let foo4: Foo = {
    one: '',
    two:3
    someFunc : (a: number) => a.toString()
} // err
```

Comment: Great Thanks. Works Great.

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
type Foo =
  | {one: string, two: number, someFunc(args: string): string}
  | {one: string, someFunc(args: number): string}
```

Comment: Thanks For all the help bcherny appreciate it.